# Why is $scope undefined?

Tags: angularjs

I'm pulling my hair out trying to build an app with angular and express. Does anybody know why $scope is coming up undefined:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp' , ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider

.when('/' , {
    templateUrl: '/index',
    controller: 'mainController'
})

});

app.controller('mainController' , function($scope){

})
```

Comment: What's in the '/index' file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you template code has a angular directive or double binding calling a $scope (demo plnkr would help).

Your controller is missing a $scope in the controller block:

```
app.controller('mainController' , function($scope){
    //no $scope here...
})
```

Look in your template for a model, then match that name with a $scope in your controller, like so:

```
app.controller('mainController' , function($scope){
    $scope.whatever = 'blah blah';
})
```

Comment: I'm so new to Angular. Didn't realize that $scope had to be attached to ngModel in the template. What is demo plnkr?

Comment: When I first started with angular, I had the same problem :) plnkr = plnkr.co it makes it easy to share simple working examples of code, like so: http://plnkr.co/edit/PdDmUz?p=preview